# Flutter How to remove map inside of List

Tags: list, flutter, maps

Hello everyone I have a list of maps. And I want to use `removeWhere()`  method with this.

My List is here:

```
List<Map<String?, dynamic>> servicesList= [
                    {
                      'title': services[0].title,
                      'price': services[0].price,
                    },
                    {
                      'title': services[1].title,
                      'price': services[1].price,
                    },
                    {
                      'title': services[2].title,
                      'price': services[2].price,
                    },
```

I am using like this because with another button, I am adding some maps inside this list.

But whenever I want to `removeWhere()` method I failed.

```
 servicesList.removeWhere(
                    (item) =>
                        item ==
                        ({
                          'title': services[0].title,
                          'price': services[0].price,
                        }),
                  );
print(servicesList);
```

It doesn't work with it. How do I handle with this method ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `mapEquals` instead of `==` since `==` technically is comparing pointers not values, like

```
List<Map<String?, dynamic>> servicesList= [
                    {
                      'title': 'title0',
                      'price': 'price0',
                    },
                    {
                      'title': 'title1',
                      'price': 'price1',
                    },
                    {
                      'title': 'title2',
                      'price': 'price2',
                    },];
                    
  servicesList.removeWhere(
                    (item) =>
                     mapEquals(item,
                        ({
                          'title': 'title0',
                          'price': 'price0',
                        })),
                  );
print(servicesList);
```

you also need to import:

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
```

Comment: Thank you. Can you help me to find if this list contains any item ? I mean ```servicesList.contains``` method.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 servicesList.removeWhere(
                    (item) => item['title'] == services[0].title);
```